# Deriving terminal velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

In my book (Young and Freedman's University Physics) they derive terminal velocity where and use these steps:

> ...we must find the relationship between velocity and time during the interval before the terminal speed is reached. We go back to Newton's second law, which we rewrite using $a_y = dv_y/dt$:
>   $$m\frac{dv_y}{dt} = mg - kv_y$$
>   After rearranging terms and replacing $mg/k$ by $v_t$, we integrate both sides, noting that $v_y=0$ when $t=0$:
>   $$\int_0^v \frac{dv_y}{v_y-v_t} = -{k\over m} \int_0^t dt$$
>   which integrates to
>   $$\ln\frac{v_t-v_y}{v_t} = -{k\over m}t\mathrm{\qquad or \qquad}1-{v_y \over v_t}=e^{-(k/m)t}$$
>   and finally
>   $$v_y=v_t[1-e^{-(k/m)t}]$$
>   Note that $v_y$ becomes equal to the terminal speed $v_t$ only in the limit that $t \to\inf$; the ball cannot attain a terminal speed in any finite length of time.

The step I don't understand is how they say that
$$\int_0^v \frac{dv_y}{v_y-v_t} = \ln \frac{v_t-v_y}{v_t}$$
By my calculations, we have
$$\int_0^v \frac{dv_y}{v_y-v_t} = \ln(v_y-v_t)\rvert_0^v = \ln(v-v_t)-\ln(-v_t) = \ln(\frac{v-v_t}{-v_t}) = \ln(\frac{v_t-v}{v_t}) \neq \ln\frac{v_t-v_y}{v_t}$$
**How does the book arrive at its answer and how is my derivation wrong?**

**For that matter, what do $v$ and $t$ even represent, since their meanings were not defined?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have simply renamed $v$ to be $v_y$ after doing the integral. Myself I would have used $v_y$ for the upper limit on the integral and $v$ for the integration variable. Their answer is correct however you read it.

Comment: How can you rename variables without changing the meaning of the equation?

Comment: The context is everything. You can rename as you wish. Obviously the correct expression has $v_y$ in it as plain $v$ has not been assigned a physical meaning except in an intermediate bit of algebra..

Comment: Plain $v$, as you say, has not been assigned a physical meaning, but $v_y$ has. To rename $v$ to $v_y$ would be to assert that $v$ can take on the physical meaning of $v_y$. Why is $v$ able to do so? And if it is able to do so, why did we need to introduce a new variable in the first place, when we already have the variable $v_y$ that we could have used instead of $v$?

Comment: For the obvious reason that the author of the book mixed them up when he wrote that bit.